# Script to Kill Remote Session and Open a Program only works if user is an administrator

Tags: rdp, sketchup

I have this code which successfully kills my remote session and opens up Sketchup.
When I remote back in, Sketchup is open and available to use.
However, it only works if the user is an administrator.
Is it possible to change this script so it works for standard users?
Even if I had to put the local administrator credentials, I would be fine with that.

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
timeout /t 15
cd "C:\Program Files\SketchUp\SketchUp 2019"
sketchup.exe

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the user has to be an administrator. You should be able to save the script in a .bat file and right click Run As Administrator. Doesn't that work?

One important point here is that SketchUp will also run with admin privileges and you wouldn't want any program running with elevated privileges unnecessarily. I would modify the script as such:

runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "C:\Program Files\SketchUp\SketchUp 2019\SketchUp.exe"

Edit: Here's a variation of the script which works for me under a regular user:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%A in ('"query session | find "Active""') DO (tscon %%C /dest:console)
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "C:\Program Files\SketchUp\SketchUp 2020\SketchUp.exe"
```

(You have to run the script as Admin)

Comment: Of course you have to be an administrator to run tscon.exe.
If you run it as an administrator, then it is looking for the administrator's session, not the user's and you get the error:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>(C:\WINDOWS\System32\tscon.exe Disc /dest:console )
Sessionname Disc not found.

I want to be able to run as in the  standard user session,
but maybe just supply administrator credentials.

Comment: Edited my answer with a more complete script which I believe works.

Comment: Does not work.  Still get access denied.  The Sketchup is not the problem.  The problem is that TSCON.EXE has to be run as an administrator, not the Sketchup

Comment: C:\Users\CR#5\Desktop>for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %A in ('"query session | find "Active""') DO (tscon %C /dest:console )

C:\Users\CR#5\Desktop>(tscon 2 /dest:console )
Could not connect sessionID 2 to sessionname console, Error code 5
Error [5]:Access is denied.